# Assertion Error while Debugging

Tags: c, assert

I'm currently working on a code to allow two people to play a dice game. You "roll" two dice, and if you roll doubles you earn 5 points unless: 1) the doubles are two sixes, at which point you earn 25 points; or 2) the doubles are two threes, at which point the entire player's point count is erased.

I've currently got something throwing me assertion errors when I debug. Specifically, it says that format != nullptr.

I'm not really sure what's happening here. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code.

```
/*This program allows users to play the dice game Fifty, where they roll a pair of dice to obtain doubles.
  Any set of doubles except for threes or sixes earn the player 5 points. Sixes earn the player 25 points.
  If the player rolls a pair of threes, their entrie score will be reset to 0. Play continues until one
  player reaches fifty points. At this point, the game ends and the players have the chance to start a new
  game.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//This function will generate a random number for the dice roll.
int roll(void);
//This function will compare the two dice rolls to see if they are doubles and compute the correct score change.
int compareDiceRoll(int diceRollOne, int diceRollTwo, int turnNumber, int playerOneScore, int playerTwoScore);
//This function will print out the players' current scores.
void printPlayerScores(int playerOneScore, int playerTwoScore);

int main(void)
{
/*//Declaring variables
//These variables will be storing the dice rolls to compare the numbers to see if the player receives points or if points are deducted.
int diceRollOne, diceRollTwo;
//These variables track the players' scores.
int playerOneScore, playerTwoScore;
//These variables determine the amount by which a player's score is incremented.
int playerOneScoreIncrement, playerTwoScoreIncrement;
//This variable determines which turn the game is on.
int turnNumber;*/
//This variable determines whether the users will quit the game or not.
char quit;

//Initializing the variables
int diceRollOne = 0, diceRollTwo = 0, playerOneScore = 0, playerTwoScore = 0, playerOneScoreIncrement = 0, playerTwoScoreIncrement = 0;
int turnNumber = 1;

//This seeds the random number function with the current internal system time to keep the numbers as random as possible.
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

for (; (playerOneScore < 15 && playerTwoScore < 15);)
{
    //This section "rolls" the dice.
    diceRollOne = roll();
    diceRollTwo = roll();

    //Prints the dice roll.
    printf("\nYour dice roll is: %d %d\n\n", diceRollOne, diceRollTwo);

    //Compare the dice roll to determine the score increment.
    if (turnNumber = 1)
    {
        scanf_s(compareDiceRoll(diceRollOne, diceRollTwo, turnNumber, playerOneScore, playerTwoScore), &playerOneScoreIncrement);
    }
    else
        scanf_s(compareDiceRoll(diceRollOne, diceRollTwo, turnNumber, playerOneScore, playerTwoScore), &playerTwoScoreIncrement);
    //Increment the score.
    playerOneScore = playerOneScore + playerOneScoreIncrement;
    playerTwoScore = playerTwoScore + playerTwoScoreIncrement;

    //Print the scores.
    printPlayerScores(playerOneScore, playerTwoScore);

    printf("Would you like to continue playing: Y/N ?\n\n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &quit);

    if (quit == 'N')
    {
        printf("\nThank you for playing!\n\n");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        turnNumber++;
        turnNumber = (turnNumber + 1) % 2;
    }
}
}

//This creates a random number between 1 and 6.
int roll(void)
{   
    int randomNumber = (rand() % 6) + 1;

    return randomNumber;
}

//This function compares the dice rolls and determines the increase in the players' scores.
int compareDiceRoll(int diceRollOne, int diceRollTwo, int turnNumber, int playerOneScore, int playerTwoScore)
{
    int playerOneScoreIncrement, playerTwoScoreIncrement;

//This section determines if the player has rolled doubles and if so, what should happen to their score.
if (diceRollOne == diceRollTwo)
{
    if (turnNumber == 1)
    {
        if ((diceRollOne == 1) || (diceRollOne == 2) || (diceRollOne == 4) || (diceRollOne == 5))
        {
            playerOneScoreIncrement = 5;
            return playerOneScoreIncrement;
        }
        else if (diceRollOne == 6)
        {
            playerOneScoreIncrement = 25;
            return playerOneScoreIncrement;
        }
        else
        {
            playerOneScoreIncrement = -1 * playerOneScore;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if ((diceRollOne == 1) || (diceRollOne == 2) || (diceRollOne == 4) || (diceRollOne == 5))
        {
            playerTwoScoreIncrement = 5;
            return playerTwoScoreIncrement;
        }
        else if (diceRollOne == 6)
        {
            playerTwoScoreIncrement = 25;
            return playerTwoScoreIncrement;
        }
        else
        {
            playerTwoScoreIncrement = -1 * playerTwoScore;
            return playerTwoScoreIncrement;
        }
    }
}
//This section is for the non-double rolls.
else
{
    if (turnNumber == 1)
    {
        playerOneScoreIncrement = 0;
        return playerOneScoreIncrement;
    }
    else
    {
        playerTwoScoreIncrement = 0;
        return playerTwoScoreIncrement;
    }
}
}

//This function prints the current player scores.
void printPlayerScores(int playerOneScore, int playerTwoScore)
{
    printf("The current scores are:\nPlayer 1: %d\nPlayer 2: %d\n\n", 
playerOneScore, playerTwoScore);
}
```

Comment: first "gcc -g code.c" then "gdb a.out" and type run.  "bt" is backtrace, "li" will list the code and you can go "up" and "down" the stack trace printing variables.

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: Since it uses `scanf_s` I assume it is Visual Studio. Check your `scanf_s(compareDiceRoll(...))` calls, `scanf_s` requires a string format but I don't think you really want to use `scanf_s` there at all.

Comment: Well I guess you're pass a null pointer to some function that you shouldn't be, such as scanf_s

Comment: You're right! I made a dumb mistake, I just needed to call my function. I fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

I messed up my scanf_s parameters, so the error is fixed!